# RSS Parsing for Image Android

Tags: android, image, rss

i wanna parsing rss data and only give image links;
view-source:http://rss.feedsportal.com/c/32727/f/510259/index.rss
that is link for rss.

images are suach as

```
<description>Olimpiyat Oyunları’nda basketbol, şimdiye kadar ABD ile başlamış ve ABD ile bitmiştir. En büyük dominasyonu kurdukları da olur, başarısız...&lt;img width='1' height='1' src='http://rss.feedsportal.com/c/32727/f/510259/s/219c12d9/mf.gif' border='0'/&gt;&lt;div class='mf-viral'&gt;&lt;table border='0'&gt;&lt;tr&gt;&lt;td valign='middle'&gt;&lt;a href="http://share.feedsportal.com/viral/sendEmail.cfm?lang=en&amp;title=21%3A08+Sovyetlerin+zafer+gecesi&amp;link=http%3A%2F%2Fspor.milliyet.com.tr%2Fsovyetlerin-zafer-gecesi%2Fbasketbol%2Fspordetay%2F23.07.2012%2F1570693%2Fdefault.htm" target="_blank"&gt;&lt;img src="http://res3.feedsportal.com/images/emailthis2.gif" border="0" /&gt;&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/td&gt;&lt;td valign='middle'&gt;&lt;a href="http://res.feedsportal.com/viral/bookmark.cfm?title=21%3A08+Sovyetlerin+zafer+gecesi&amp;link=http%3A%2F%2Fspor.milliyet.com.tr%2Fsovyetlerin-zafer-gecesi%2Fbasketbol%2Fspordetay%2F23.07.2012%2F1570693%2Fdefault.htm" target="_blank"&gt;&lt;img src="http://res3.feedsportal.com/images/bookmark.gif" border="0" /&gt;&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/td&gt;&lt;/tr&gt;&lt;/table&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;br/&gt;&lt;br/&gt;&lt;a href="http://da.feedsportal.com/r/139262466254/u/192/f/510259/c/32727/s/219c12d9/a2.htm"&gt;&lt;img src="http://da.feedsportal.com/r/139262466254/u/192/f/510259/c/32727/s/219c12d9/a2.img" border="0"/&gt;&lt;/a&gt;&lt;img width="1" height="1" src="http://pi.feedsportal.com/r/139262466254/u/192/f/510259/c/32727/s/219c12d9/a2t.img" border="0"/&gt;</description>
```

how can i parse it?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I miswunderstand you but you can try the

```
Html.fromHtml(img, new ImageGetter() {

@Override
public Drawable getDrawable(String source) {

 }
}, null);
```

to retrive images from the Html you get when you parse the RSS. (source is the path to the image)

Answer (score 0):

i think if you display discription node data in webView  than it automatically gets the image..

```
webView.loadData(here description node value, "text/html", null);
```